# My client server application run in eclipse emulator but not in real android mobile phone

Tags: android, python, client-server, emulation

I wrote a client server program ,that my client is android and my server is python, in the client side I input data in edittext and when press a button ,data is sent to server via internet and in server data save to my SQLite database.my server and mobile device are attach to a modem through WIFI so I used the local IP to my program and I used socket for transfer data via internet.
My problem is this, my application work correctly in emulator when the server and emulator are in the same computer but when I run my android application in a real device it can't connect to the server, my application run but when I press button my application is stop and exit.
thanks for your help.
I'm sure my python server is correct I tested it with telnet and there isn't any problem in connection between client and server.I think my client side program have a problem.

My server side code with python

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import socket
import sqlite3


serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "192.168.1.4"
port = 4444
print (host)
print (port)
serversocket.bind((host, port))

serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server started and listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("connection found!")
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print (data)
    row=data.split(" ", 3)
    a=row[0]
    b=row[1]
    c=row[2]
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO victims values (?,?,?)",(a,b,c));
    conn.commit()
    print ("Records created successfully")

conn.close()
s.close ()
```

my client side code with android

package com.alizade.m;

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.net.Socket; 
import java.net.UnknownHostException; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.EditText; 


public class Client3 extends Activity {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField1;
    private EditText textField2;
    private EditText textField3;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage1;
    private String messsage2;
    private String messsage3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
    textField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); //reference to the text field
    textField3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); //reference to the text field
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button
    final TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //Button press event listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    messsage1 = textField1.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
    textField1.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank
    messsage2 = textField2.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
    textField2.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank
    messsage3 = textField3.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
    textField3.setText("");

    try {

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.4"); 


     client = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);  //connect to server
     printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
     printwriter.write(messsage1);  //write the message to output stream
     printwriter.write(" ");
     printwriter.write(messsage2);
     printwriter.write(" ");
     printwriter.write(messsage3);
     printwriter.flush();
     printwriter.close();
     tv.setText("sent");
     client.close();   //closing the connection

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    });

    }
}
```

it's LogCat

```
06-09 13:27:15.127: D/AndroidRuntime(453): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-09 13:27:15.127: D/AndroidRuntime(453): CheckJNI is ON
06-09 13:27:18.707: D/AndroidRuntime(453): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-09 13:27:18.917: D/AndroidRuntime(453): Shutting down VM
06-09 13:27:18.957: I/AndroidRuntime(453): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-09 13:27:19.047: D/dalvikvm(453): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 296K/1024K, external   0K/0K, paused 19ms+10ms
06-09 13:27:19.077: D/jdwp(453): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-09 13:27:19.077: D/dalvikvm(453): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-09 13:27:21.846: D/AndroidRuntime(464): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-09 13:27:21.856: D/AndroidRuntime(464): CheckJNI is ON
06-09 13:27:22.867: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address  family not supported by protocol
06-09 13:27:25.378: D/AndroidRuntime(464): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-09 13:27:25.967: D/dalvikvm(230): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 54% free 2545K/5511K, external   1625K/2137K, paused 212ms
06-09 13:27:26.007: W/ActivityManager(70): No content provider found for: 
06-09 13:27:26.177: W/ActivityManager(70): No content provider found for: 
06-09 13:27:26.257: D/PackageParser(70): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1838012416.tmp
06-09 13:27:26.807: I/PackageManager(70): Removing non-system package:com.alizade.m
06-09 13:27:26.807: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package com.alizade.m uid=10034
06-09 13:27:27.257: I/Process(70): Sending signal. PID: 444 SIG: 9
06-09 13:27:27.577: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '4068bb68 com.alizade.m/com.alizade.m.Client3 (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-09 13:27:27.577: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '4068bb68 com.alizade.m/com.alizade.m.Client3 (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-09 13:27:27.957: I/WindowManager(70): WINDOW DIED Window{4068bb68 com.alizade.m/com.alizade.m.Client3 paused=false}
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70): Failed looking up window
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@406119b0 does not exist
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8174)
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8165)
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70):    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowManagerService.java:7024)
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70):    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:381)
06-09 13:27:28.126: W/WindowManager(70):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-09 13:27:28.146: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: null
06-09 13:27:28.926: W/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 444 uid 10034
06-09 13:27:30.138: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 37K, 44% free 3459K/6151K, external 6952K/7268K, paused 596ms
06-09 13:27:33.717: D/PackageManager(70): Scanning package com.alizade.m
06-09 13:27:33.788: I/PackageManager(70): Package com.alizade.m codePath changed from /data/app/com.alizade.m-1.apk to /data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-09 13:27:34.008: I/PackageManager(70): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk
06-09 13:27:34.247: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk' ---
06-09 13:27:35.489: D/dalvikvm(473): DexOpt: load 124ms, verify+opt 435ms
06-09 13:27:35.550: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk' (success) ---
06-09 13:27:35.606: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package com.alizade.m uid=10034
06-09 13:27:35.626: W/PackageManager(70): Code path for pkg : com.alizade.m changing from /data/app/com.alizade.m-1.apk to /data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk
06-09 13:27:35.626: W/PackageManager(70): Resource path for pkg : com.alizade.m changing from /data/app/com.alizade.m-1.apk to /data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk
06-09 13:27:35.647: D/PackageManager(70):   Activities: com.alizade.m.Client3
06-09 13:27:36.430: D/dalvikvm(230): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 54% free 2543K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 160ms
06-09 13:27:36.898: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.alizade.m-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.alizade.m-2.apk@classes.dex
06-09 13:27:36.906: D/PackageManager(70): New package installed in /data/app/com.alizade.m-2.apk
06-09 13:27:36.936: W/PackageManager(70): Not granting permission android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH to package com.alizade.m (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be46)
06-09 13:27:37.846: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package com.alizade.m uid=10034
06-09 13:27:38.490: D/dalvikvm(70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 524K, 49% free 4352K/8519K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 541ms
06-09 13:27:38.769: D/dalvikvm(153): GC_EXPLICIT freed 74K, 51% free 2879K/5831K, external 4698K/5604K, paused 907ms
06-09 13:27:39.497: W/RecognitionManagerService(70): no available voice recognition services found
06-09 13:27:41.347: D/dalvikvm(70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 192K, 50% free 4328K/8519K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 954ms
06-09 13:27:41.557: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.alizade.m-1.apk@classes.dex
06-09 13:27:41.747: D/dalvikvm(181): GC_EXPLICIT freed 95K, 52% free 2759K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 2891ms
06-09 13:27:41.877: D/AndroidRuntime(464): Shutting down VM
06-09 13:27:42.317: D/dalvikvm(464): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 294K/1024K, external  0K/0K, paused 138ms+3ms
06-09 13:27:42.417: D/jdwp(464): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-09 13:27:42.417: D/dalvikvm(464): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-09 13:27:45.466: D/AndroidRuntime(478): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-09 13:27:45.466: D/AndroidRuntime(478): CheckJNI is ON
06-09 13:27:49.330: D/AndroidRuntime(478): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-09 13:27:49.580: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.alizade.m/.Client3 } from pid 478
06-09 13:27:50.629: D/AndroidRuntime(478): Shutting down VM
06-09 13:27:50.669: I/AndroidRuntime(478): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-09 13:27:50.857: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc com.alizade.m for activity com.alizade.m/.Client3: pid=487 uid=10034 gids={3003}
06-09 13:27:51.447: D/dalvikvm(478): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 10ms+7ms
06-09 13:27:51.687: D/jdwp(478): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-09 13:27:51.687: D/dalvikvm(478): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-09 13:27:56.520: D/dalvikvm(329): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 11133ms
06-09 13:27:56.817: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed com.alizade.m/.Client3: +6s260ms
06-09 13:28:05.378: D/dalvikvm(290): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 55% free 2595K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 233ms
06-09 13:28:10.506: D/dalvikvm(153): GC_EXPLICIT freed 65K, 50% free 2968K/5831K, external    4748K/5604K, paused 333ms
06-09 13:28:12.917: W/KeyCharacterMap(487): No keyboard for id 0
06-09 13:28:12.927: W/KeyCharacterMap(487): Using default       keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Comment: Your device and server are on same network??

Comment: yes both of them are connected to a same modem ,my server IP is 192.168.1.4 and my mobile phone is 192.168.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your firewall disabled for this port on your server? Maybe it is blocking it. Try to look int he LogCat output for exceptions / uncaught exceptions, null pointer error.

Update:

You have the requiered permission in your android manifest .xml?

First of all if you provide your IP address to InetAddress then change the method:

```
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.4");
```

to:

```
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte [] {192, 168, 1, 4});
```

You can also try to set a breakpoint where you define the onclick listener for your button, and step-by-step you will see where your app crashes (F6 in eclipse), on connected device to a computer of course.

**Update:**

Man, now I'm blushing :) How come I didn't notice that you are trying to do network communication on the main thread. You need to do it in a thread or asynctask.

You can do this in 2 ways, the better I think is asynctask:

```
     private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField1;
private EditText textField2;
private EditText textField3;
private Button button;
private String messsage1;
private String messsage2;
private String messsage3;
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
textField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); //reference to the text field
textField3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); //reference to the text field
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//Button press event listener
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

messsage1 = textField1.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
textField1.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank
messsage2 = textField2.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
textField2.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank
messsage3 = textField3.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
textField3.setText("");

new ServerPingPong().execute();

}
});

}

private class ServerPingPong extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.69"); 


         client = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);  //connect to server
         printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
         printwriter.write(messsage1);  //write the message to output stream
         printwriter.write(" ");
         printwriter.write(messsage2);
         printwriter.write(" ");
         printwriter.write(messsage3);
         printwriter.flush();
         printwriter.close();

         client.close();   //closing the connection

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         tv.setText("sent");
    }


}
```

Or the easier way, but not so fancy :) :

```
    new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {

          InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.4"); 

          client = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);  //connect to server
          printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
          printwriter.write(messsage1);  //write the message to output stream
          printwriter.write(" ");
          printwriter.write(messsage2);
          printwriter.write(" ");
          printwriter.write(messsage3);
          printwriter.flush();
          printwriter.close();
          tv.setText("sent");
          client.close();   //closing the connection

      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }.start();
```

Tested both ways and it worsk.

Secondly, you did not provide the proper LogCat log. There's almost no information about your application work. Try to read about using LogCat, it's very helpful in finding erros. You probably had a NetworkOnMainthread Fatal Exception.

Comment: Ok, so as Ahmed Nawaz suggested, are the devices on the same network? Did you check the logcat output?

Comment: I check it but I can't understand problem , I insert myLogCat top of this page

Comment: Ok, i assume that you have required permissions in your android manifest. I'm updating answer, check it.

Comment: I changed that line but did't run

Comment: ok, now try :) somehow I omitted the fact that you've tried to do network operation on main thread.

Comment: No problem glad to help, remember just that every network operation needs to be executed in another thread, not in the UI thread